# Wcf service sending list of class objects with null values

Tags: wcf, list, class, object, contract

The issue is when wcf service is sending the list of class objects to client, the values are null. Any help or guidance is appreciated.

**My service interface is**

### **IPswdService.cs**

```
namespace GetPasswordsSvc
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IPswdService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<dbVal> GetData(int value);
    }

[DataContract]
    public class dbVal
    {
        public string Group;
        public string Title;
        public string Username;
    } ;
}
```

---

### GetPasswords.svc.cs

```
namespace GetPasswordsSvc
{
    public class PswdService : IPswdService
    {

       public List<dbVal> GetData(int value)
        {
          List<dbVal> kpdata= (from entry in db.RootGroup.GetEntries(true)
                         select new dbVal
                         {
                             Group = entry.ParentGroup.Name,
                             Title = entry.Strings.ReadSafe("Title"),
                             Username = entry.Strings.ReadSafe("UserName"),
                         }).ToList();

            List<dbVal> l = kpdata.ToList();
             return l;
        }
```

======================================

## WCF Client code

```
SvcRef.PswdServiceClient wcfClient = new SvcRef.PswdServiceClient();
wcfClient.Open();
List<GetPasswords.dbVal> dbValues = wcfClient.GetData(0);
```

==============================================

### The client config file is

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPswdService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://xxxxxxx:444/GetPasswords.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPswdService" contract="SvcRef.IPswdService"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IPswdService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: I forgot to add the [DataMember] tags to the attributes in dbVal class. After adding it, the issue was solved. This is what happens, when things run on caffeine for extended period.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell exactly what the cause is, but jus glancing at your service data contract, I can see that you've missed out the `DataMember` attribute on your data contarct fields, your data contract should be:

```
[DataContract]
public class dbVal
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Group;
    [DataMember]
    public string Title;
    [DataMember]
    public string Username;
}
```